# npm install devtool -g ,Error

Tags: npm, electron

```
sudo npm install devtool -g
Password:
/usr/local/bin/devtool -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/devtool/bin/index.js

> fsevents@1.1.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/devtool/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/devtool/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v51-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

> electron@1.4.15 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/devtool/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/devtool/node_modules/electron/install.js:46
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/devtool/node_modules/electron/electron-tmp-download-1555-1488050976880/SHASUMS256.txt' -> '/Users/sheepyellow/.electron/SHASUMS256.txt-1.4.15'
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "devtool" "-g"
npm ERR! node v7.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! electron@1.4.15 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.4.15 postinstall script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the electron package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs electron
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: So your question is why is this permission denied?

Comment: Isn't DevTool part of Electron?